# parsing a json response from an API with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, parsing

I'm trying to parse a json response from an API but buy altering some existing PHP code I created however I'm having difficulty. This is the json response

```
"response":{
  "status":"ok",
  "userTier":"free",
  "total":10,
  "startIndex":1,
  "pageSize":10,
  "currentPage":1,
  "pages":1,
  "results":[{
    "id":"lifeandstyle/series/cycling",
    "type":"series",
    "webTitle":"Cycling",
    "webUrl":"http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/series/cycling",
    "apiUrl":"http://content.guardianapis.com/lifeandstyle/series/cycling",
    "sectionId":"lifeandstyle",
    "sectionName":"Life and style"
  }
```

Trying to parse all the information within the "webTitle" and "webUrl" sections

```
<?php 
require_once 'Zend/Json.php'; 
$val = Zend_Json::decode($result); 
$arr = $val; 
if(preg_match_all("~<p>([\s\S]*?)</p>~i", $arr['parse']['text']['*'], $matches)){ 
if(is_array($matches[1])) foreach($matches[1] as $paragraph){ 
echo $paragraph;
}
}
?>
```

This code just parses content in p tags, how would I alter it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% clear on your question.  Zend_Json::decode uses json_decode under the hood, which is what @psion was referring to.  I assume **$result** in your example

```
$val = Zend_Json::decode($result);
```

holds the json you pasted beforehand.

It looks to me like the json you posted is invalid or at least incomplete (because there is a missing *]* and a missing *}*).  I'm not sure what this has to do with parsing **p** tags, but anyway here's an example that parses the json and extracts the components you're interested in.  It peels off the leading *"response":* bit from the json before decoding as well.

```
<?php
$sJson = '"response":{
  "status":"ok",
  "userTier":"free",
  "total":10,
  "startIndex":1,
  "pageSize":10,
  "currentPage":1,
  "pages":1,
  "results":[{
    "id":"lifeandstyle/series/cycling",
    "type":"series",
    "webTitle":"Cycling",
    "webUrl":"http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/series/cycling",
    "apiUrl":"http://content.guardianapis.com/lifeandstyle/series/cycling",
    "sectionId":"lifeandstyle",
    "sectionName":"Life and style"
  }]}';
$sJson = substr($sJson, strpos($sJson, ':') + 1);

// feel free to replace json_decode w/ Zend_Json::decode
$aNative   = json_decode($sJson);

$sWebTitle = $aNative->results[0]->webTitle;
$sWebUrl   = $aNative->results[0]->webUrl;

echo 'Web Title: ' . $sWebTitle . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Web URL  : ' . $sWebUrl . PHP_EOL;
```

Here's the output from the script

```
Web Title: Cycling
Web URL  : http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/series/cycling
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by parse? The JSON reply is ready to be used as soon as you decode it. You don't have a `$arr['parse']...` you have `$arr['webTitle']` which contains "Cycling". What do you want to parse inside "Cycling"?

Also, what is the deal with assigning the result to $val and then assigning $val to $arr? Assign straight to $arr.

Do print_r($val) and look at what you have. That will give you a better idea of what you need to do. Most likely you are making things more complicated than they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Tthere are json function within PHP that do not require calling Zend functions.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php